# deployment, service, ingress implemented. Got default backend - 404

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am practicing `k8s` `deployment, service, and ingress` implementation from [here](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/create-kubernetes-ingress-routes) on `GKE`. Clicking through the simulator help me quickly understand concept, but when I do hands on. I stuck `default backend - 404`. Here are my manifest files and `bash` description.

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tunnel-deployment
  labels:
    app: tunnel
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tunnel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tunnel
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tunnel
        image: gcr.io/k8s-v1-235608/tunnel:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: MONGODB_HOST
            value: moon-mongodb-replicaset-client
          - name: RABBIT_HOST
            value: rodent-rabbitmq-headless
          - name: RABBIT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: rodent-rabbitmq
                key: rabbitmq-password
          - name: REDIS_HOST
            value: ninja-redis-ha
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
```

See `deployments` in `bash`

```sh
$ kubectl get deployments -o wide
NAME                DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                               SELECTOR
tunnel-deployment   1         1         1            1           11m   tunnel       gcr.io/k8s-v1-235608/tunnel:latest   app=tunnel
```

See `po` in `bash`

```sh
$ kubectl get po -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE                                  NOMINATED NODE
bbox                                1/1     Running   0          1d    10.4.0.6    gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-pxnz   <none>
moon-mongodb-replicaset-0           1/1     Running   0          1d    10.4.2.9    gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-lcs6   <none>
moon-mongodb-replicaset-1           1/1     Running   0          1d    10.4.0.8    gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-pxnz   <none>
moon-mongodb-replicaset-2           1/1     Running   0          1d    10.4.2.10   gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-lcs6   <none>
ninja-redis-ha-server-0             2/2     Running   0          1d    10.4.0.9    gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-pxnz   <none>
ninja-redis-ha-server-1             2/2     Running   0          1d    10.4.1.11   gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-85ch   <none>
ninja-redis-ha-server-2             2/2     Running   0          1d    10.4.2.11   gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-lcs6   <none>
rodent-rabbitmq-0                   1/1     Running   0          1d    10.4.2.12   gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-lcs6   <none>
tunnel-deployment-fddf78dcc-lpq8l   1/1     Running   0          11m   10.4.1.37   gke-doom-default-pool-4b763b09-85ch   <none>
```

`service.yaml`. I use `NodePort` with my `tunnel-service`. 
With my `selection.app`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tunnel-service
  labels:
    app: tunnel
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: tunnel-port
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: tunnel
```

Then I have single `IP` address to represent my `service`.

```sh
$ kubectl describe svc tunnel-service
Name:                     tunnel-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=tunnel
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"tunnel"},"name":"tunnel-service","namespace":"default"},...
Selector:                 app=tunnel
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.7.242.110
Port:                     tunnel-port  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 tunnel-port  32713/TCP
Endpoints:                10.4.1.37:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

`ingress.yaml`. I route the `/` to my `tunnel-service`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tunnel-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.hbot.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: tunnel-service
          servicePort: 80
```

```sh
$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             tunnel-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.244.186.216
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.1.9:8080)
Rules:
  Host         Path  Backends
  ----         ----  --------
  abc.hbot.io
               /   tunnel-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:                    {"k8s-be-31768--d2232907436d0807":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32713--d2232907436d0807":"UNHEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:             k8s-fw-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:                k8s-tp-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s-um-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"tunnel-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"abc.hbot.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"tunnel-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}]}}

Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     16m   loadbalancer-controller  default/tunnel-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  15m   loadbalancer-controller  ip: 35.244.186.216
```

In my browser. I had routed my hostname to my correct DNS and got `default backend - 404`

I confirm my `pod` in `deployment` works. My endpoint does response on my request.

```sh
bash-4.3# curl http://localhost:8080/api
Hi I'm API Interface
```

**Update on Attempt #1**:
Add `*` after `/` and `apply`

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
ingress.extensions/tunnel-ingress configured

$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             tunnel-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.244.186.216
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.1.9:8080)
Rules:
  Host         Path  Backends
  ----         ----  --------
  abc.hbot.io
               /*   tunnel-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:                    {"k8s-be-31768--d2232907436d0807":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32713--d2232907436d0807":"UNHEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:             k8s-fw-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:                k8s-tp-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s-um-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"tunnel-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"abc.hbot.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"tunnel-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/*"}]}}]}}

Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     42m   loadbalancer-controller  default/tunnel-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  40m   loadbalancer-controller  ip: 35.244.186.216
```

Not work.

**Attempt #2**
Add `annotations`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tunnel-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.hbot.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: tunnel-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Check the `ingress`

```sh
$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             tunnel-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.244.186.216
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.1.9:8080)
Rules:
  Host         Path  Backends
  ----         ----  --------
  abc.hbot.io
               /   tunnel-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:                    {"k8s-be-31768--d2232907436d0807":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32713--d2232907436d0807":"UNHEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:             k8s-fw-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:                k8s-tp-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s-um-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx"},"name":"tunnel-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"abc.hbot.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"tunnel-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}]}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     54m   loadbalancer-controller  default/tunnel-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  53m   loadbalancer-controller  ip: 35.244.186.216
```

> Error: Server Error
>   The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

**Attemp #3**
Install `ingress-nginx` to cluster. I follow the `cert-manager` [doc](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/blob/master/docs/tutorials/acme/quick-start/index.rst). Because I used it once with former cluster.

Follow the same name.

```sh
$ helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name quickstart

NAME:   quickstart
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Mar 27 16:09:15 2019
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/ConfigMap
NAME                                 DATA  AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress-controller  1     0s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                                                       READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress-controller-5b8d54d964-rnvw6       0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
quickstart-nginx-ingress-default-backend-57bdfdcd46-vtf4h  0/1    Pending            0         0s

==> v1/Service
NAME                                      TYPE          CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)                     AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress-controller       LoadBalancer  10.7.241.190  <pending>    80:32341/TCP,443:32762/TCP  0s
quickstart-nginx-ingress-default-backend  ClusterIP     10.7.254.207  <none>       80/TCP                      0s

==> v1/ServiceAccount
NAME                      SECRETS  AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress  1        0s

==> v1beta1/ClusterRole
NAME                      AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress  0s

==> v1beta1/ClusterRoleBinding
NAME                      AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress  0s

==> v1beta1/Deployment
NAME                                      READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress-controller       0/1    1           0          0s
quickstart-nginx-ingress-default-backend  0/1    1           0          0s

==> v1beta1/Role
NAME                      AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress  0s

==> v1beta1/RoleBinding
NAME                      AGE
quickstart-nginx-ingress  0s


NOTES:
The nginx-ingress controller has been installed.
It may take a few minutes for the LoadBalancer IP to be available.
You can watch the status by running 'kubectl --namespace default get services -o wide -w quickstart-nginx-ingress-controller'

An example Ingress that makes use of the controller:

  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    name: example
    namespace: foo
  spec:
    rules:
      - host: www.example.com
        http:
          paths:
            - backend:
                serviceName: exampleService
                servicePort: 80
              path: /
    # This section is only required if TLS is to be enabled for the Ingress
    tls:
        - hosts:
            - www.example.com
          secretName: example-tls

If TLS is enabled for the Ingress, a Secret containing the certificate and key must also be provided:

  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: example-tls
    namespace: foo
  data:
    tls.crt: <base64 encoded cert>
    tls.key: <base64 encoded key>
  type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

`describe ingress`

```sh
$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             tunnel-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.244.186.216
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.1.9:8080)
Rules:
  Host         Path  Backends
  ----         ----  --------
  abc.hbot.io
               /   tunnel-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:                    {"k8s-be-31768--d2232907436d0807":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32713--d2232907436d0807":"UNHEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:             k8s-fw-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:                k8s-tp-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s-um-default-tunnel-ingress--d2232907436d0807
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx"},"name":"tunnel-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"abc.hbot.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"tunnel-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}]}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  5m12s                nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/tunnel-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  7s (x7 over 92m)     loadbalancer-controller   ip: 35.244.186.216
  Normal  UPDATE  7s (x13 over 5m12s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/tunnel-ingress
```

Test with `curl` on my laptop

```sh
$ curl -H 'Host: abc.hbot.io' 35.244.186.216/api

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

**Attempt 4th:**
Solve `insufficient cpu` otherwise my new `pods` will not run
`values.yaml`

```
controller:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 64Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 64Mi

defaultBackend:
  resources:
   limits:
     cpu: 10m
     memory: 20Mi
   requests:
     cpu: 10m
     memory: 20Mi
```

Install `ingress-nginx`
`helm install --values values.yaml stable/nginx-ingress --name quickstart`

`ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tunnel-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

spec:
  rules:
    - host: abc.hbot.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: tunnel-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
```

`describe ingress`

```sh
$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             tunnel-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.240.162.185
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.1.9:8080)
Rules:
  Host         Path  Backends
  ----         ----  --------
  abc.hbot.io
               /   tunnel-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx"},"name":"tunnel-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"abc.hbot.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"tunnel-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}]}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age    From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----   ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  14m    nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/tunnel-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  14m    nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/tunnel-ingress
  Normal  UPDATE  14m    nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/tunnel-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  9m27s  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/tunnel-ingress
```

I delete and apply ingress again. IP address is changed

```sh
$ kubectl get ingress -o wide
NAME             HOSTS         ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
tunnel-ingress   abc.hbot.io   35.240.162.185   80      15m
```

My situation is even worse.

```sh
$ curl -H 'Host: abc.hbot.io' http://35.240.162.185/api
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.240.162.185 port 80: Connection refused
```

**Final Attempt #5:**
I gave up using plain `http` setup. And start over with `https` approach. By following `cert-manager` and then replace `kuard` service by my service. Then it is done!

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, perhaps you need to use this annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` if you are using nginx-ingress controller or the name of the ingress-controller in GKE

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question refer to your comment.

Comment: Are you in fact using nginx-ingress controller? (did you install it?) or using the default GKE ingress mechanism? If you did not install nginx-ingress controller then you should not specify this annotation

Comment: @PierreB. No. I did not install `nginx-ingress`. Do I need that?

Comment: I think that causes your `502` when you set `nginx-ingress`. The `default-backend` error may be caused by your browser no handling DNS re-definition well (I had the same issue), a more reliable test would be to run `curl -H 'Host: abc.hbot.io' 35.244.186.216` - this will make sure the Ingress rules handle your host definition

Comment: @PierreB. `$ curl -H 'Host: abc.hbot.io' 35.244.186.216/api
default backend - 404`. I am now trying `ingress-nginx`. One moment.

Comment: Could you make it work?

Comment: @Emixam23 No it doesn't. I gave up and follow another tutorial

Comment: I la asking because I have a similar issue but can’t find out why, please check my last question on SO if you can...

Answer (score 0):

I never used GKE, but with AWS and ALB, the path needs to include the wildcard.
It seems that it's the same on GKE.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_6_optional_serving_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer

Try to configure your ingress as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tunnel-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.hbot.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: tunnel-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I have updated my attempt refer to your answer.